# DC.js Composite line chart unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to plot a composite chart using dc containing 2 line charts.

The lines are getting rendered but are some how entangled as shown in the picture below

[image]

I also tried changing the elastic x,y properties but it did not improve the situation.

Can anyone help me out here?
Below is the code being used to create the above chart:

```
 lineChart_addChurn
 .width(300)
.height(200)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function (d) {return d.Month;})))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.clipPadding(10)
.compose([
    dc.lineChart(lineChart_addChurn)
        .dimension(dim_line_month)
        .colors('red')
        .interpolate('step-after')
        .renderArea(false)
        .renderDataPoints(true)
        .group(group_line_adds, "Top Line"),
    dc.lineChart(lineChart_addChurn)
        .dimension(dim_line_month)
        .colors('blue')
        .interpolate('step-after')
        .renderArea(false)
        .renderDataPoints(true)
        .group(group_line_churn, "Bottom Line")
    ])
.brushOn(false)
.render();
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: sort your data on basis of date

Comment: Although I don't understand why it should happen, because I was using the same unsorted data for another simple line chart and did not face this error, but sorting the data worked for me here! Thanks :)

Comment: The chart will display the data in the order returned by the group. [Which is wrong.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/598) Since your group is ordinal, the sorting order is alphabetical, so Apr, Feb, Jan, Jul, Mar, May makes sense. Of course, it should respect the domain/sorting order, as prescribed in the linked issue.